# 'minikube start' issue on Windows 10

Tags: minikube

I am on Windows 10. Command 'systeminfo' shows:

> Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

but when I run 'minikube start':

```
* minikube v1.9.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.17134 Build 17134
* Unable to pick a default driver. Here is what was considered, in preference order:
  - virtualbox: Not installed: unable to find VBoxManage in $PATH
  - vmware: Not installed: exec: "docker-machine-driver-vmware": executable file not found in %PATH%
  - docker: Not healthy: exit status 1
  - hyperv: Not installed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online failed:
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature : The requested operation requires elevation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.GetWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand


  - podman: Not installed: exec: "podman": executable file not found in %PATH%
  - Try specifying a --driver, or see https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/
```

How to get it working?

Comment: Did any of the below answers help you get it to work ?

Comment: Not really, but then there was a window update and it started working :)

Comment: OK, so let's post it as Community Wiki answer for better visibility to show that this issue was solved in the end.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a Community Wiki answer, posted for better visibility, so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

OP confirmed in comments that **this issue disappeared after Windows update**:

> Not really, but then there was a window update and it started working
> :) – [Mandroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2444661/mandroid)

So the problem with **hyperv** in this case was in general OS-related.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [specify driver you want to use](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#specifying-the-vm-driver) with minikube, in this case it will be `hyperv`. So in order to start minikube you have to run

`minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv`.

If Hyperv was not previously enabled you have to run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All` and reboot your machine.

If you want to use hyper-v as default driver you can run `minikube config set driver hyperv`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker then go for

sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker

minikube start --driver=docker

Comment: worked with me as I was trying to install on ubunutu AWS EC2

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make it work is to follow leads from error message itself where at the last, it says as follows:

```
Try specifying a --driver, or see https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/
```

If URL is followed then it details what all could be done to solve this issue.

URL - https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Answer (score 0):

**Try to run the same command `minikube start` on CMD run as Administrator mode**

Steps to run CMD as Administrator:

> 1. Search CMD in Windows Search Prompt
> 2. Right-click on the CMD App and Select Run as Administrator
> 3. Run Command `minikube start`

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu try to do this:

```
sudo service docker start
```

then

```
minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable kubernetes under docker desktop settings:
[image]